# Java: Store and Serialize Items from an Array

Tags: java, serialization, for-loop

I know this could be a very easy question but I cant get my code to work properly. I need to write into a XML file in an field an example like this: 1-A,2-C,3-D,...25-A
For this I have the total number of items (1..25) and the answers given for these items that I retrieve from another class.
Here is what I use to write this kind XML and what does not work as I should work.

```
for (int i=0;i<=30;i++){
                nRespuesta  = i+1;
                nRespuestaString = Integer.toString(nRespuesta);
                Respuesta = Verbal.getRespuestas(i);
                RespuestaString = nRespuestaString+"-"+Respuesta+",";

            }
serializer.startTag(null, "RESPUESTAS");
            serializer.text("RespuestaString");
            serializer.endTag(null, "RESPUESTAS");
```

With this code it only shows the last item, how could I show all?
Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**UPDATE**
Answer now uses StringBuilder for better performance.

You need to [concatenate](http://java.about.com/od/c/g/concatenation.htm) the string rather than overwrite on each loop iteration so modify your code to the following:

```
StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
for (int i=0;i<=30;i++){
                nRespuesta  = i+1;
                nRespuestaString = Integer.toString(nRespuesta);
                Respuesta = Verbal.getRespuestas(i);
                //Note the change on the line below
                sb.append(nRespuestaString).append("-").append(Respuesta).append(",");
            }
serializer.startTag(null, "RESPUESTAS");
            serializer.text(sb.toString());
            serializer.endTag(null, "RESPUESTAS");
```

Comment: How about teaching some best practices, as in "don't concatenate in a loop---use StringBuilder"?

Comment: @MarkoTopolnik Good point - I'll check the syntax and update the answer. For my reference, does the compiler not perform this optimization?

Comment: It can't possibly perform the optimization I have in mind, which is building up a string in a loop. `javac` will only compile a single concatenation expression consisting of more than two operands into a `StringBuilder` idiom.

Comment: OK, thanks for pointing that out @MarkoTopolnik and @sm4. I've updated the answer to use `StringBuilder`

Comment: To teach the correct idiom, never use concatenation within `append`. Use `append(x).append(y)...`. The way you havet in now, you are forcing the instantiation of an implicit `StringBuilder` in each iteration.

Comment: Hopefully the best practices suggested by @MarkoTopolnik are implemented correctly now too.

Answer (score 2):

First, you are overwriting the string with values and not appending:

`RespuestaString = nRespuestaString+"-"+Respuesta+",";`

To make the code nicer and clearer, use StringBuilder class to create the String.

Also this line:

`serializer.text("RespuestaString");`

Simply puts the value 'RespuestaString' into the XML. I believe you wanted to write:

`serializer.text(RespuestaString);`